# Mongoose returning more than one result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I have the following collection structure :

```
{
    name : 'name1'
    projects : [
      {projectId : 123 , ...more},
      {projectId : 124 , ...more},
      {projectId : 125 , ...more},
    ]
  }
  
  {
    name : 'name2'
    projects : [
      {projectId : 126 , ...}
      {projectId : 127 , ...}
    ]
  }
```

My goal is to find a single project based on it's projectId. So if I were to look for a project with the ID of 123, my result should be :  `{projectId : 123 , ...more}`

But right now it's returning everything :

```
 {
        name : 'name1'
        project : [
          {projectId : 123 , ...more},
          {projectId : 124 , ...more},
          {projectId : 125 , ...more},
        ]
      }
```

My query looks like :

```
   const project = await ClientManager.findOne({
      'project.projectId': projectId,
    });


{
    "projectId" : "123",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you had a match, with your current project, it returns the whole document. What you want to do is use the $elemMatch operator and use it in your projection.

It would look something like this

```
 const project = await ClientManager.findOne({
  project: {$elemMatch: { projectId: projectId } },
}, {'project.$': 1});
```

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/ for more details